# multiple divs pointing to same tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to create a personal website for me and I am a beginner in html and css. In my work section, i have created multiple buttons which open a small window and give the description of the project. The issue i am facing is all different divs are pointing to last div and the content of the last div is getting copied in all other divs. Thank you so much in advance for helping me out.

Below is the content of my last div:

[image]

Below is my image of second div:

[image]

Below is the overall code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".call_modal").click(function() {
    $(".modal").fadeIn();
    $(".modal_main").show();
  });
});
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".close").click(function() {
    $(".modal").fadeOut();
    $(".modal_main").fadeOut();
  });
});
```

```css
work body {
  margin: 0;
  background: #e5eaee;
}

h3 {
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #e1c184;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 50px 0px 0px;
  clear: both;
}

.modal {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  display: none;
}

.modal_close {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  margin-left: -8px;
}

.close {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.gl1_content .modal_main {
  width: 50%;
  height: 500px;
  background: #B7BBBE;
  z-index: 4;
  position: fixed;
  top: 16%;
  border-radius: 4px;
  left: 25%;
  overflow: auto;
  -webkit-animation-duration: .5s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: .0s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
  -moz-animation-fill-mode: both;
  -o-animation-fill-mode: both;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: visible!important;
  -webkit-animation-name: fadeInRight;
  text-align: center;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeInRight {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(20px)
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0)
  }
}

.gl1_content .content {
  padding: 50px 0px 30px;
  text-align: justify;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

button {
  display: block;
  width: 25%;
  height: 150px;
  padding: 40px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #3399cc;
  border: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #fff;
  margin-top: 40px;
  margin-left: 80px;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  position: center;
}

.ProjTable {
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 50%;
}

.ProjTable td,
#ProjTable th {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 8px;
}

.ProjTable tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

.ProjTable tr:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.ProjTable th {
  padding-top: 12px;
  padding-bottom: 12px;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://gc.kis.v2.scr.kaspersky-labs.com/B55FB9A2-E45C-3242-96D3-CF26E54EC901/main.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>

<h3 id="work">Work</h3>

<div class="gl_content">
  <button class="call_modal" style="cursor:pointer;">SAS Consult and Support</button>
  <div class="modal">
    <div class="modal_close close"></div>
    <div class="modal_main">
      <img src="i783wQYjrKQ.png" class="close" style="margin-top:13px;left:96%;position:fixed;">
      <div class="content">
        <p></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="content">
  <button class="call_modal" style="cursor:pointer;">Global Reporting Infrastructure Project (GRIP)</button>
  <div class="modal">
    <div class="modal_close close"></div>
    <div class="modal_main">
      <img src="i783wQYjrKQ.png" class="close" style="margin-top:13px;left:96%;position:fixed;">
      <div class="content">
        <p><strong>Global Reporting Infrastructure Project (GRIP)</strong> is a key global initiative and is aimed at delivering a set of standard reports with standard metrics, definitions and templates across RBWM products Origination, Portfolio Management,
          Profitability and RWAs by providing a global platform for Risk data aggregation and reporting. RBWM Risk has historically lacked Group level risk aggregation and reporting capability and relied upon end user computing to produce executive reporting
          to drive risk management and decision making. Numerous inconsistencies relating to Key Performance Indicators (KPI) captured, business definitions used, calculations performed and report formats utilized are inherent with this method of reporting.
          RBWM Risk management desires a system that will provide more metrics and KPIs to drive better decision making and analysis.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

A generic approach can be:

a) First add a common class(like- 'modal_container') to all the modal containers.

```
<div class="gl_content modal_container">...</div>
...
<div class="content modal_container">...</div>
...
```

b) On click event get the immediate modal container element on top of the element that got clicked and show/hide the modal inside it(the modal container).

I have redesigned the code below, please check with it:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".call_modal").click(function(){
    var modal_container = $(this).closest('.modal_container');
    $(".modal", modal_container).fadeIn();
    $(".modal_main", modal_container).show();
  });

  $(".close").click(function(){
    var modal_container = $(this).closest('.modal_container');
    $(".modal", modal_container).fadeOut();
    $(".modal_main", modal_container).fadeOut();
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, Tanvir. It works. I can't say how much i am relieved.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change this line of code :

```
$(".modal").fadeIn();
```

to be :

```
$(this).next($(".modal")).fadeIn();
```

In this case: When you click at any button, the `div` with class `modal` after the clicked button only will be work.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".call_modal").click(function() {
    $(this).next($(".modal")).fadeIn();
    $(".modal_main").show();
  });
});
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".close").click(function() {
    $(".modal").fadeOut();
    $(".modal_main").fadeOut();
  });
});
```

```css
work body {
  margin: 0;
  background: #e5eaee;
}

h3 {
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #e1c184;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 50px 0px 0px;
  clear: both;
}

.modal {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  display: none;
}

.modal_close {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  margin-left: -8px;
}

.close {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.gl1_content .modal_main {
  width: 50%;
  height: 500px;
  background: #B7BBBE;
  z-index: 4;
  position: fixed;
  top: 16%;
  border-radius: 4px;
  left: 25%;
  overflow: auto;
  -webkit-animation-duration: .5s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: .0s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
  -moz-animation-fill-mode: both;
  -o-animation-fill-mode: both;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: visible!important;
  -webkit-animation-name: fadeInRight;
  text-align: center;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeInRight {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(20px)
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0)
  }
}

.gl1_content .content {
  padding: 50px 0px 30px;
  text-align: justify;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

button {
  display: block;
  width: 25%;
  height: 150px;
  padding: 40px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #3399cc;
  border: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #fff;
  margin-top: 40px;
  margin-left: 80px;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  position: center;
}

.ProjTable {
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 50%;
}

.ProjTable td,
#ProjTable th {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 8px;
}

.ProjTable tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

.ProjTable tr:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.ProjTable th {
  padding-top: 12px;
  padding-bottom: 12px;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h3 id="work">Work</h3>

<div class="gl_content">
  <button class="call_modal" style="cursor:pointer;">SAS Consult and Support</button>
  <div class="modal">
    <div class="modal_close close"></div>
    <div class="modal_main">
      <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/34950/pexels-photo.jpg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=350" class="close" style="margin-top:13px;left:96%;position:fixed;">
      <div class="content">
        <p></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="content">
  <button class="call_modal" style="cursor:pointer;">Global Reporting Infrastructure Project (GRIP)</button>
  <div class="modal">
    <div class="modal_close close"></div>
    <div class="modal_main">
      <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTQxuLL7OoxpB8Eju7xawRbmtMl855M2e09m1-_30NDM8i_m2vr" class="close" style="margin-top:13px;left:96%;position:fixed;">
      <div class="content">
        <p><strong>Global Reporting Infrastructure Project (GRIP)</strong> is a key global initiative and is aimed at delivering a set of standard reports with standard metrics, definitions and templates across RBWM products Origination, Portfolio Management,
          Profitability and RWAs by providing a global platform for Risk data aggregation and reporting. RBWM Risk has historically lacked Group level risk aggregation and reporting capability and relied upon end user computing to produce executive reporting
          to drive risk management and decision making. Numerous inconsistencies relating to Key Performance Indicators (KPI) captured, business definitions used, calculations performed and report formats utilized are inherent with this method of reporting.
          RBWM Risk management desires a system that will provide more metrics and KPIs to drive better decision making and analysis.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```